# VisualState example in c++?

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml, visualstatemanager

Can someone provide a C++ example for the following equivalent C#?

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "statename", true);
```

I don't know C++ and am working to convert some animations for another group. The MSDN examples are blank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
VisualStateManager::GoToState(this, "statename", true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the noob question.